# Running audio engine in separate thread/process, sending and receiving messages from main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, swift, nsthread

I'm writing an iOS application using a separate audio engine which is built in C++. The idea is to have as much of the app as possible written in Swift, running the audio engine as a separate thread or process, and then let the user interface trigger communication with the audio engine.

How is this best achieved?

My first try was to add an intermediate Objective-C++ class (TestEngine) that handles triggering the appropriate C++ code. This Objective-C++ class I initiate in Swift like this:

```
// Initialize audio engine
let engine = TestEngine()

// Start engine in a new thread
NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(NSSelectorFromString("startEngine"), toTarget: engine, withObject: nil)
```

The TestEngine class looks like this:

```
@implementation TestEngine

- (void) startEngine {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(selectorMethod)
     name:@"testSelector"
     object:nil];

    NSLog(@"StartEngine done on thread:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);

}

- (void) selectorMethod {
    NSLog(@"This is selector, on thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Now deallocing");
}

@end
```

The problem now is that the object is deallocated right away, before it is able to receive any notifications. I have also tried looking into RunLoops, but haven't been able to find any easy (not too low-level) way to add observers to the RunLoop. Any ideas of how such a solution is best designed on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here there's your answer

Quoting Apple docs

> Regular notification centers deliver notifications on the thread in
>   which the notification was posted. Distributed notification centers
>   deliver notifications on the main thread. At times, you may require
>   notifications to be delivered on a particular thread that is
>   determined by you instead of the notification center. For example, if
>   an object running in a background thread is listening for
>   notifications from the user interface, such as a window closing, you
>   would like to receive the notifications in the background thread
>   instead of the main thread. In these cases, you must capture the
>   notifications as they are delivered on the default thread and redirect
>   them to the appropriate thread.

Comment: And any idea of how I redirect them to the appropriate thread?

Comment: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doA) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread does not seem to exist in Swift. Any equivalent way of doing this in Swift?

Comment: I ended up creating an extra layer of ObjC code, and from there doing the required [object perfermSelector: @selector(doA) onThread: thread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];, then calling this code from Swift.